# Calculus problem, fluid dynamics with Gauss's form of gravity

Tags: fluid-dynamics, newtonian-gravity, gauss-law

Is this derivation correct?
$$\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}=-\nabla\cdot(\rho \overline{u})\qquad (1)$$
$$\nabla\cdot \overline{g}=4\pi G \rho \qquad (2)$$
If we differentiate with respect to $t$ equation (2), we have:
$$\nabla\cdot (\frac{\partial\overline{g}}{\partial t})=4\pi G \frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}=-4\pi G\nabla\cdot(\rho \overline{u}) $$
$$\nabla\cdot (\frac{\partial\overline{g}}{\partial t})+4\pi G\nabla\cdot(\rho \overline{u})=0 $$
$$\nabla\cdot (\frac{\partial\overline{g}}{\partial t}+4\pi G(\rho \overline{u}))=0 $$

$$\frac{\partial\overline{g}}{\partial t}+4\pi G(\rho \overline{u})=constant? $$

Comment: If the divergence of a quantity is zero does it mean that the quantity is constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Newtonian gravity, we have $\nabla \times \vec{g}=0$.

Therefore, let's express $\vec{g}$ as the (negative) gradient of a scalar potential $\phi$ without any loss of generality.

So, we define $\vec{g}=-\nabla \phi$

Now, your equation $(2)$ reads as $\nabla^2=-4\pi G\rho$

Taking its time derivative, we get $\nabla^2 \dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}=-4\pi G \dfrac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}$

Plugging in your equation $(1)$ in this result gives us $\nabla^2\dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}=4\pi G  (\nabla  \cdot(\rho \vec{u}))$

Or, $\nabla \cdot \bigg(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\nabla\phi - 4\pi G\rho\vec{u}\bigg)=0$

So, we can say, there exists a vector potential $\vec{A}$ so that $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\nabla\phi - 4\pi G\rho\vec{u} = \nabla \times \vec{A}$

Taking a curl and remembering that the curl of a gradient vanishes, we get

$$4\pi G(\nabla \times (\rho\vec{u})) = \nabla^2\vec{A} - \nabla (\nabla \cdot \vec{A}) \tag{$\alpha$}$$

But again, we know that the curl of a gradient vanishes and thus, we redefine our vector potential to be $\vec{\mathcal{A}}=\vec{A} + \nabla\lambda$ where we define $\lambda$ to be determined by $\nabla^2\lambda + \nabla \cdot \vec{A}=0$. This way, we get $\nabla \cdot \vec{\mathcal{A}} =0$

Therefore equation $(\alpha)$ for the redefined vector potential $\mathcal{A}$ reduces to $4\pi G(\nabla \times (\rho\vec{u})) = \nabla^2\vec{\mathcal{A}}$

Now, we can have our explicit formula for $\dfrac{\partial \vec{g}}{\partial t}$ as the following:

$$\dfrac{\partial \vec{g}}{\partial t} = 4\pi G\rho \vec{u} + \nabla \times \vec{\mathcal{A}}$$

Where, $\vec{\mathcal{A}}$ is any solution (all will give the same result for $\dfrac{\partial \vec{g}}{\partial t}$) of the following: $$4\pi G(\nabla \times (\rho\vec{u})) = \nabla^2\vec{\mathcal{A}}$$

Answer (score 1):

All that implies from your last equation is
$$\frac{\partial \vec{g}}{\partial t} + 4\pi G(\rho \vec{u}) = \nabla \times \vec{A}$$

for some vector field $\vec{A}$.

To show your desired result, you might want to try showing
$$\nabla \times \left(\frac{\partial \vec{g}}{\partial t} + 4\pi G(\rho \vec{u})\right) = 0$$

or simply try a different approach.

Comment: Since the curl of $\vec{g}$ is zero in Newtonian gravity, your last equation essentially says that we got to make $\rho \vec{u}$ curl-free. This doesn't need to be generically true. So, in a generic case, we can't prove something like your last equation.